# prepopulate database

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea

For test purposes I'm trying to prepopulate a table which is created by Hibernate. I have this in my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<!-- Prepopulate database with these DML scripts -->
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/genres.sql</property>
```

I have added the file `genres.sql` to the root of my `src` folder but it doesn't execute the file?

This is the `genres.sql` file:

```
INSERT INTO genre (naam) VALUES ("Action");
INSERT INTO genre (naam) VALUES ("Adventure");
INSERT INTO genre (naam) VALUES ("Animation");
INSERT INTO genre (naam) VALUES ("Biography");
INSERT INTO genre (naam) VALUES ("Comedy");
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file **IS** in the classpath as it's under `/src` directory but IntelliJ only looks for specific extensions, `.sql` is not one of them.

By going to settings or using the shortcut `CTRL+ALT+S` you go to `Compiler` and on the right you have `Resource Patterns`, add the `.sql` extension there and it works fine.